# Adding an Image to a filled.contour plot in R - or the other way around

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to plot a heatmap with `filled.contour` with a background image. I know that `filled.contour` are actually two plots and that one can add, e.g., points with `plot.axes`. Can you make this work with images as well? The following code plots the image ontop of the heatmap, but I'd like to have the picture as background.

```
MyFunction <- function(x,y){
  return(dnorm(sqrt(x^2+y^2)))
}
wrapper <- function(x, y, my.fun, ...) {sapply(seq_along(x), FUN = function(i) my.fun(x[i], y[i], ...))}
meshstep <- 0.5
x<- seq(-20,20,meshstep)
y <-seq(-20,20,meshstep)
z <- outer(x,y,FUN = wrapper, my.fun=MyFunction)
image <- readPNG("imagepath\\image.png")
filled.contour(
  x,y,z, col=rev(heat.colors(n=20, alpha=0.7)), nlevels=15,plot.axes={
    rasterImage(image, x[1], y[1],x[length(x)],y[length(y)]);
    points(0,0,pch=4)
  })
```

Another way to solve this would be something like

```
plot(x,y,type="n")
rasterImage(image, x[1], y[1],x[length(x)],y[length(y)])
filled.contour(x,y,z, add=TRUE)
```

instead of the last `filled.contour` call in the MWE, but unfortunately, there is no `add=TRUE` option for `filled.contour`.

Should I just head for `lattice`'s `levelplot`?

Comment: why not using `image` and `contour` instead of `filled.contour`? They both have an `add` option. You lose the key but it's not that hard to draw a key separately.

Comment: What happens, using `filled.contour` , if you specify the fill colors to have transparency (e.g. `col=c(#ff00ff88,00ff0088)` ) ?

Comment: I believe this is what he is doing: `col=rev(heat.colors(n=20, alpha=0.7))`

Comment: The code above puts the picture in the foreground and the heatmap is behind it and not visible. I'd like to have the image as a background and the heatmap in the foreground.